# Safely authorize an HTTP request with JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, authorization

This quite tricky. I would prefer having serverside key authorization, but we are limited to a JavaScript only implementation. Customers will use a JavaScript library, that will request certain pieces of data - but this customer has to be authorized to use this data. That's where the authorization part comes in, that does not involve any serverside (At the customers side) implementation.

The JavaScript library is requesting data at my server, but not all customers are allowed to see every piece of data. Thats why I need to authorize the customer.

Currently I simply place a customer-ID in the JavaScript library which is being sent to the server to authorize. This is not very safe though, you could simply copy this ID over to your own library to get data from the server you can normally not retrieve.

I don't need a 100% waterproof solution, but my current implementation is just pure garbage. As the solution needs to be pure JavaScript, I understand there will be many ways to spoof the authorization. I just need something some authorization that's the safest as it will get with JavaScript only. Any idea?

Comment: Any real security here would be impossible, and while I dont know what you goal is here I would recommend a deeper redesign rather then spinning your wheels trying trying to fake something thats impossible -- it would be dishonest to any customer of your development work for you to present this to them as 'security' and dangerous to you if this is for personal projects.

Comment: @gbtimmon I understand that, and I have said that in my OP. However, I'm sure there are better aproaches than my current implementation.

Comment: _I just need something some authorization that's the safest as it will get with JavaScript only_ -- you get none. That's the best you can do.

Comment: Note also that if your customers use that JavaScript library on their own pages, then anybody viewing those pages will be able to copy the customer ID and use it.

Comment: @Pointy That's also what I said in my OP. And the security level does not need to be high in any way at all, just better than this stupid ID stuff.

Comment: Any solution will eventually boil down to _this stupid ID stuff_. You can obfuscate but eventually the ID is going to have to be sent to the server to fetch the data, that's where your vulnerability is.